# Can't infer the type of instance variable '@id' of Document

Tags: type-inference, crystal-lang

I have the following class which is actually view model and I'm trying to initialize it based on the database model like so:

```
class Document

  @id   : Int64
  @name : String

  JSON.mapping(
    id: Int64,
    name: String,
  )

  def initialize(db_model)
    @id   = db_model.id
    @name = db_model.name
  end

end
```

Here is the example data model:

```
class DatabaseModel < ActiveRecord::Model

  @@connection_pool_capacity = 25
  @@connection_pool_timeout  = 0.03

  adapter postgres

  table_name database_model

  primary id  : Int
  field name  : String

end
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> in src/models/document.cr:10: instance variable '@id' of Document must be Int64, not (Int16 | Int32 | Int64 | Int8 | Int::Null | UInt16 | UInt32 | UInt64 | UInt8)

I'd like to do this the most semantically correct way.  Whats the best way to infer the correct type in this situation?

Comment: Did you try declaring the specific `Int` type matching your database, probably `Int64`, in your database model?

Answer (score 3):

There is no inference involved in this error. It's just a type mismatch between expected `Int64` for `Document#@id` vs `Int` returned by `DatabaseModel#id`.

There are two ways to resolve this: either convert `dv_model.id` to `Int64` using `#to_i64` or type `DatabaseModel#id` as `Int64`. The latter is probably the preferred way because usually there is no point in storing an I'd as different Int datatypes.